# How do I keep content centered in CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, centering

Using CSS Grid Layout, I create a site whose layout changes a little with screen size.

Here, in order to keep the content (pink area) in the CSS Grid Layout central, I did the following styling.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #6c757d;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20%, 1fr) auto minmax(20%, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
}

h1,
dl {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: pink;
}

p.h6 {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  p.h6 {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
}

body>p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer class="bg text">
  <h1>
    heading
  </h1>
  <dl class="h6">
    <dt>word1</dt>
    <dd>desc1</dd>
    <dt>word2</dt>
    <dd>desc2</dd>
  </dl>
  <p class="h6">COPYRIGHT(C)loooooooooooooooooooooooooongtext</p>
</footer>
<p>&#8593;<br>true center</p>
```

This seems to work well when the width is wide, **but when the width is smaller, the pink area deviates from the "true center"**.

This also shows that **`minmax (20%, 1fr)` does not work** well.

How can I keep this pink area centered? Also, is there a better way than the one I thought above? (With CSS Grid Layout)

Comment: you are simply having overflow, 40% + min content width (width of heading) is more than 100%

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes it is. There is a problem with the code I thought. The code I thought is centered in the pink area, but it is not centered due to screen width etc. How do you generally solve these (mostly `overflow`) problems with CSS Grid Laylout?

Comment: simply change the minmax() by only `1fr`, I don't really see the need of  `20%` here

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you use only `1fr`, when the smaller the screen, the pink area will be pushed to the left by the copyright text. This will use the `minmax` function, as the pink area will no longer be a "true center".

Comment: because you are using a *strange* long string. add some spaces and it will be fine. I don't think you will really have such copyright

Comment: @TemaniAfif Surprisingly, the original Copyright is twice as long as this long string.

Comment: it's not about *long*, it's about space .. I don't think you will have a long string without any space, such word doesn't exist

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s5j9tb7q/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr` for centering the middle column. Now add `min-width: 0` on the `p.h6` so that you override the default `min-width: auto` of *grid items* to allow it to shrink past content size (*overflow* value other than visible also works) - this allows `overflow-wrap: break-word` to take effect. See demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #6c757d;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr; /* changed */
  /*grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto); <-- redundant */
}

h1,
dl {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: pink;
}

p.h6 {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 0; /* added */
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  p.h6 {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
}

body>p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer class="bg text">
  <h1>
    heading
  </h1>
  <dl class="h6">
    <dt>word1</dt>
    <dd>desc1</dd>
    <dt>word2</dt>
    <dd>desc2</dd>
  </dl>
  <p class="h6">COPYRIGHT(C)loooooooooooooooooooooooooongtext</p>
</footer>
<p>&#8593;<br>true center</p>
```

Comment: @bafeaski let me know your thoughts on this, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this rule:

`p.h6 {
  grid-column: 3;
}`

When the width of the viewport is over 800px, the text in the p.h6 element, i.e. this: "COPYRIGHT(C)loooooooooooooooooooooooooongtext"

takes up the far right column, grid-column 3. The pink box in the center then can be very small. This is because you have set `grid-template-columns` for the footer element to this:

`grid-template-columns: minmax(20%, 1fr) auto minmax(20%, 1fr);`

In other words, the columns surrounding the pink box should be as big as possible (1fr), while the pink box should be as small as possible (auto, or the width of the text inside).

Now, when the viewport is **less** than 800px, the copyright text moves to the 2nd, or middle column:

`@media (max-width: 800px) {
  p.h6 {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
}`

This forces the `auto` width of that column to be the entire width of the "loooooooongtext." That's why it overflows the viewport when you shrink it too small.

You can fix this by adding two property values to the direct children of the footer:

`footer > *{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
  }`

Both go in the `max-width: 800px` media query. Demo:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #6c757d;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20%, 1fr) auto minmax(20%, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
}

h1,
dl {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: pink;
}

p.h6 {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  p.h6 {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  
  footer{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  footer > *{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

body>p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer class="bg text">
  <h1>
    heading
  </h1>
  <dl class="h6">
    <dt>word1</dt>
    <dd>desc1</dd>
    <dt>word2</dt>
    <dd>desc2</dd>
  </dl>
  <p class="h6">COPYRIGHT(C)loooooooooooooooooooooooooongtext</p>
</footer>
<p>&#8593;<br>true center</p>
```